# WPA and WPS: connection method

Tags: key-exchange, wpa2-psk

Do clients use WPS every time when they connect to a WPS-enabled AP? Or maybe they do it just the first time and then they switch to a normal WPA/WPA2 key exchange?

If the latter, it's possible for an AP to force a client to use WPS every time?

Comment: Cross posting on multiple SE sites is [against SE rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/223134). This was also posted on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83704/wps-and-wpa2-connection-methods)